# How to encode decode a struct that contains Dictionary

Tags: json, swift, codable

I want to make a struct Codable so I can write contents to a file

```
   struct LocationDetails: Codable {
    var locationId: String? = nil
    var providerId: String? = nil
    var locationDict = [String:Any]()
    var providerDict = [String:Any]()
   }
```

Gives error : Type 'LocationDetails' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'.

Instead of Dictionary if I use an Array and encode/decode the struct with PropertyListEncoder and PropertyListDecoder it works fine. But won't even allow me to define a dictionary inside codable struct
How to make the struct with Dictionary Codable?

Comment: The problem is not the dictionary. It is the Any. You need a nested struct here or a single value type in the dictionary, if you want to use Codable.

Comment: struct LocationDetails: Codable {
    var locationId: String? = nil
    var providerId: String? = nil
    var locationDict = [String:Codable()
    var providerDict = [String:Codable]()
   }; I tried that, now it says does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Comment: Nope, `[String:Codable]` is not a Decoable type either.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your comments at first. If I make it specific type like Dictionary <String, String>(). That works. But I some times I have to store string, and sometimes images, int etc in the same dictionary that is why I used Any. Is there a way to address that?

Comment: Yes, as I said, use a custom nested struct not a dictionary. If you want to use Codable. A totally random hodge podge dictionary cannot be Codable, the whole idea makes no sense.

Comment: Yes I will go with nested structs

Answer (score 0):

You can define the struct using generics as follows to remove the `Any` type and constrain your dictionary *value* types to those that conform to `Codable`.

BTW: If you're only saving (not loading), you should use `Encodable`, rather than `Codable`.

```swift
struct LocationDetails<Location: Codable, Provider: Codable>: Codable {
 var locationId: String? = nil
 var providerId: String? = nil
 var locationDict = [String:Location]()
 var providerDict = [String:Provider]()
}
```

Comment: I am keeping it simple for now as suggested by Matt - just structs and dictionaries of same type